# Unable to connect to Twitter API from Vagrant box

Tags: api, twitter, oauth, vagrant

I am trying to connect to a Twitter API endpoint (https) from a Vagrant box (Laravel Homestead), however, I get a 401 authorization required when I try to connect.

On my local machine, everything works well. I am trying to figure out what is different in configuration, but no success. Does it has to do with the OAuth header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to update your `oauth_callback` to use your VM's ip instead of "localhost".

A good thing to do might be using this vagrant plugin [vagrant-hostsupdater](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater). Then you can set the VM hostname to something like "myproject.dev" and use that as the callback.

Comment: Installing vagrant-hostsupdater alone does the trick. Thanks.